# How to open xml files using command line for Mac OS?

Tags: command-line, macos-catalina

I have a test_12_22.xml file. I want to see the contents of the file. How can I achieve this using command line in MAC OS Catalina.

I tried **open test_12_22.xml**, but it opened a Word Document with junk information.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do that with the following command

```
open test_12_22.xml -a TextEdit
```

This will open your XML file with TextEdit, which should be able to read it.